# NSPredicate comparing transformed CLPlacemark with another CLPlacemark

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate

I'm saving `CLPlacemark` in Core data using `NSValueTransformer`. (so it's saved as `NSData`)

However I've come to a point where I need to filter the saved objects based on another `CLPlacemark` object.

I've tried this, it doesn't work:

```
NSExpression *exprPath = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"placemark"];
NSExpression *exprKeyword = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:placemark]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:exprPath rightExpression:exprKeyword modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier type:NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType options:0];
```

So any other suggestions?

Comment: Does the answer below work for you? :)

Comment: Nope, i've ended up using a sha1 hash for comparing.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data supports == and != searches against binary data (and transformable attributes). Do not use *NSKeyedArchiver* for your *placemark*. Just use it as is in predicate like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"placemark = %@", placemark]
```