# Core Data Transformable NSArray of IDs

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have an CoreData entity class X, which stores an NSArray of NSString IDs, inside a transformable attribute (lets say someIDs)...

**Given an NSString ID, how can i find (using Predicate) all entities X, which contains the ID, in their someIDs attribute?**

Note: i know about relationships (so no need to propose using a relationship) etc. but what to do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. A transformable attribute is store as a data blob in the SQLite store file (using `NSCoding` methods). The Core Data fetch request (which is translated to a SQLite query)
has no access to the contents of the transformable attribute.

If you don't want to use a to-many relationship then you can only fetch *all* objects and filter the fetched `NSArray`.

Comment: i believe its somehow possible, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204498/nspredicate-comparing-transformed-clplacemark-with-another-clplacemark

Comment: @PeterLapisu: It seems to work with == or !=, for example `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"someIDs == %@", @[@"12", @"34"]]`. In that case the right-hand side is translated to a data blob which is used in the SQLite query. You can see that if you add the launch argument "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3" to your scheme settings. It does not work for `"ANY someIDS == %@"`.

Comment: yup, so just the direct equality is tested... but still believe that there is a way for CD to handle this in ways that in unarchives the blob and performs the operation (playing with predicateWithLeftExpression)

Comment: @PeterLapisu: Let me know if you find something! - Just note that the filtering is done on the SQLite level. - For all Core Data debugging, I can only recommend to set "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3" (choose 3 or 1) to see what actually happens.