# Core Data : is it possible to use scalars as transformed NSValues in predicates?

Tags: xcode, core-data, nspredicate

If you have a struct,e.g  :

```
typedef struct _intCoord {
    int x;
    int y;
} intCoord;
```

which you store as a NSValue, how do use the resultant value in predicates?

e.g. if I store the *components* as properties like NSNumbers *xNum, *yNum the following can be used:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
  @"(xNum = %i) AND (yNum <= %i)", self.currentX, self.maxY];
```

Is it possible to write predicates to perform such filtering with NSValue properties?

Comment: You cannot use the "components" of a transformable attribute in predicates, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/21698194/1187415.

Comment: I do not see the advantage vs. just using NSNumbers.